# How to use console commands and see console output on Minecraft Thermos Server for 1.7.10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

I am using Minecraft 1.7.10 and am running a server using Thermos, a modification that allows me to use both Bukkit plugins and Forge Mods at the same time. My server runs generally perfectly, I can start it, I can connect to it, I can execute commands from in-game. However, while vanilla server comes with a nice UI itself, allowing me to see the console output and use console commands without actually entering the server myself, a Thermos server doesn't seem to. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: I don't think a special "thermos" tag is really needed. There are just 13 questions with the tags "minecraft-server" and "minecraft-modded" together, so I don't think there will be many Thermos questions.

Comment: There is a [Meta discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13122/164914) going on about the [tag:minecraft-thermos] tag. Please, don't remove the tag from the question until this discussion gets resolved. It's been 12 days since it was started, the initiative to remove the tag has 1 upvote and two downvotes as of now.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is probably setting up a .bat file to launch your server through it, following [the official instruction](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server#Creating_a_.bat_file_to_store_the_commands).

To be short, you can create a text file using Notepad or Notepad++, changing its file extension to .bat, containing the following lines:

> java -Xms512M -Xmx4096M -jar Thermos-1.7.10-1614-server.jar
>
> pause

Of course, if your Thermos file is called "Thermos-1.7.10-1614-server.jar". The "pause" thing allows you to have time to see the console output even if you stop your server or if it crashes (normally the command line window will disappear in this case).

Comment: You could also try just entering that without `pause` into a regular console.

Comment: @Fabian Indeed! But it sounds more practical to me to have a .bat file rather than to enter that all manually each time.